# Group by returns 0 instead of negative amount

Tags: sql-server, group-by

```
select sum(amount), Type, ProductName, ProductCategory
from ProductAmount
Group by Type, ProductName, ProductCategory
```

Running this query only provides positive amount and also replaces negative amount with a 0.  Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Pretty sparse on details here. I like the guesses that lad2025 put in their answer. Another option might be to simply add a where clause. "WHERE Amount > 0"

Comment: I figured out my problem.  There were some products which were returned so the amount showed (for example) -1200 and there was also another amount when the product was bought before it was returned.  So when I used SUM function, it got rid of negative amount and replaced it with 0 instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select sum(CASE WHEN amount < 0 THEN 0 ELSE amount END), Type, ProductName, ProductCategory
from ProductAmount
Group by Type, ProductName, ProductCategory
```

or using SQL Server 2012+:

```
select sum(IIF(amount < 0, 0, amount)), Type, ProductName, ProductCategory
from ProductAmount
Group by Type, ProductName, ProductCategory
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem. There were some products which were returned after they were bought.  I failed to realize that the table captures negative amount when returned and positive amount when bought.  For my case, when I used SUM function, it added the amount for a specific product and total ended up being 0.